# Populating values in select dropdowns using ngmodel, angular 8

Tags: angular

I have two dropdowns,start time and end time, the first dropdown uses a time array, where time is selected, and then index of this time is used to slice , and array is made for the second dropdown. So that end time is always greater than start time.

Here I am trying to set default values when the submit button is clicked, but when I click the submit button then I am

1. not getting the set Start time vale,it appears blank and
2. getting end time value in the dropdown, but the drop down value array also shows time values less than the start time as well.

template

```
   Start at:
                <select
                [(ngModel)]="time1"
                (change)="onSelect($event.target.value)"   id="fTime">
                 <option value="0" selected>Select</option>
                  <option  [value]="i" *ngFor="let type of startTimeArray; let i = index">
                    {{type}}
                  </option>
               </select>
               End at:
              <select 
               [(ngModel)]="time2"
               id="tTime">
                 <option value="0" selected>Select</option>
                  <option [value]="type" *ngFor="let type of tempEndTimeArray">
                    {{type}}
                  </option>
              </select>


<div><button   (click)="submit()">click</button></div>
```

TS

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { FormGroup, FormArray, FormBuilder, FormControl } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  forTableArray: any = [];
  time1:any=[];
  time2:any=[];
  startTimeArray:any=["07:00 AM","08:00 AM", "09:00 AM", "10:00 AM", "11:00 AM", "12:00 PM",  "1:00 PM",  "2:00 PM", "3:00 PM",  "4:00 PM", "5:00 PM",  "6:00 PM", "7:00 PM", "8:00 PM"];
  endTimeArray:any=["07:00 AM","08:00 AM", "09:00 AM", "10:00 AM", "11:00 AM", "12:00 PM",  "1:00 PM",  "2:00 PM", "3:00 PM",  "4:00 PM", "5:00 PM",  "6:00 PM", "7:00 PM", "8:00 PM"];
  public tempEndTimeArray: Array<any>;

  public enableEndTime: boolean = true;
  submit(){
this.time1="";
this.time2="";
this.tempEndTimeArray =this.startTimeArray;
this.time1="7:00 AM";
this.time2="5:00 PM";
  }
public onSelect(val){
  console.log(val)
  let index = parseInt(val) + 1;
  console.log(index)
   this.tempEndTimeArray = this.endTimeArray.slice(index);

}
  convertTime12to24(time12h) {
    const [time, modifier] = time12h.split(" ");
    let [hours, minutes] = time.split(":");
    if (hours === "12") {
      hours = "00";
    }
    if (modifier === "PM") {
      hours = parseInt(hours, 10) + 12;
    }
    return `${hours}:${minutes}`;
  }
}
```

Apart from that I am not able to get selected time value in my console, example if 01:00 PM is selected from the dropdown, I want it to display in the console, instead I am getting index value(as I have set [value]= i, in my html select dropdown, so that i can use slice for time)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r2sv3k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues. Instead of detailing them individually, I will show you my version of your code and describe what I have done.

**component.html**

```html
Start at:
<select [(ngModel)]="time1" (ngModelChange)="onTime1Change()">
  <option [ngValue]="-1">Select</option>
  <option  [ngValue]="i" *ngFor="let time of startTimes; let i = index">
    {{time}}
  </option>
</select>

End at:
<select [(ngModel)]="time2">
  <option [ngValue]="-1">Select</option>
  <option [ngValue]="i" *ngFor="let time of endTimes let i = index">
    {{time}}
  </option>
</select>
```

In the HTML, I am using `[ngValue]` to bind option values instead of `[value]`. `[ngValue]` binds the value itself, whereas `[value]` always uses the string representation. You want to use the index as the option values (a number), so should use `[ngValue]`.

Also, I am using a value of -1 for the placeholder option. This is to avoid a clash between `Select` and the first item in the array.

Because you are using `[(ngModel)]`, you can use `(ngModelChange)` to detect value changes. And because you are using two-way binding, you don't need to pass the value to the event handler - the model has already been updated.

**component.ts**

```js
time1 = -1;
time2 = -1;

startTimes = ["07:00 AM","08:00 AM", "09:00 AM", "10:00 AM", "11:00 AM", "12:00 PM",
  "1:00 PM",  "2:00 PM", "3:00 PM",  "4:00 PM", "5:00 PM",  "6:00 PM", "7:00 PM", "8:00 PM"];    
endTimes: string[];

ngOnInit() {
  this.endTimes = this.startTimes.slice();
}

onTime1Change() {
  if (this.startTimes.indexOf(this.endTimes[this.time2]) <= this.time1) {
    this.time2 = -1;
  }

  let sliceIndex;
  if (this.time1 >= 0) {
    sliceIndex = this.time1 + 1;
  }

  this.endTimes = this.startTimes.slice(sliceIndex);
}
```

`time1` and `time2` are being bound to the `<select>` fields, and so their data type should match the `<option>` value types. I am initialising them to -1 to allow `Select` to appear selected as default.

There is no need for an `endTimeArray` and `tempEndTimeArray` - you can always take a copy from the `startTimeArray`. I have also declared their correct data types. I am initialising `endTimeArray` in `ngOnInit()`.

`onTime1Change()` is doing all of the heavy lifting here. It performs the following actions:

1. Reset `time2` if `time2` <= `time1`. Remember that the `endTimes` may be a slice, so you have to find the original index of the time2 value in `startTimes`.
2. Set the slice index if `time1` has a value
3. Set `endTimes`

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sae1jr

Comment: @user1997 No problem. I would recommend refactoring your code to use pure dates, but I didn't want to go down that rabbit hole in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

My solution, rethink your design

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {

  public startDate: Date;
  public endDate: Date;

  public readonly availableDates: Date[] = [
      new Date(2020, 4, 13, 10),
      new Date(2020, 4, 13, 11),
      new Date(2020, 4, 13, 12),
      new Date(2020, 4, 13, 13),
      new Date(2020, 4, 13, 14),
      new Date(2020, 4, 13, 15),
    ];

  get availableEndDates() {
      if(this.startDate == undefined) return[];
      const timeStampStart = new Date(this.startDate).getTime();
      return this.availableDates.filter(d =>  {
        const timeStampEnd = new Date(d).getTime();
        return timeStampStart < timeStampEnd;
      });
  }

  public submit() {
      if(this.startDate == undefined) this.startDate = this.availableDates[0]
  }
```

}

**app.component.html**

```
Start at:
<select [(ngModel)]="startDate">
  <option [value]="undefined">No date selected</option> 
  <option [value]="date" *ngFor="let date of availableDates">
    {{date | date:'hh:mm aaaa'}}
  </option>
</select>

End at:
<select [(ngModel)]="endDate" [disabled]="startDate == undefined">
  <option [value]="undefined">No date selected</option> 
  <option [value]="date" *ngFor="let date of availableEndDates">
      {{date | date:'hh:mm aaaa'}}
  </option>
</select>

<button (click)="submit()">click</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works.But what if I had to print the value of selected time in my console, how to extract that

Comment: I assume you want to log the selected time on the validation (click the click button). so you can access to the class property startDate, a Date object which own some useful methods like .getHours():  console.log(this.startDate.getHours());